# Can MySQL generate random numbers that can be either negative or positive?

Tags: mysql, random

Is there any way in MySQL to generate a random number that can be either positive *or* negative?

For example, I want a double between `-1.0` and `1.0` rather than a double between `0.0` and `1.0` which is what [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) returns.

Comment: Someone had suggested using (RAND() - RAND()) which is close, but it has a tendency to return a value between -0.5 and 0.5 with less of a chance to hit the upper and lower limits. I ran a little test in a spreadsheet where I applied the formula across 100 rows and checked the min and max results returned. They very rarely went past -0.89 and +0.89, whereas a simple RAND() would always return a value much closer to the lower and upper limits. http://i.imgur.com/hJb3pfB.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT -1+2*RAND();
```

Should return a double between -1.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Clean and concise. @pronox's answer describes the same solution with a little more detail for anyone else looking for an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22722991/1196517

Answer (score 2):

Generically, `FLOOR(RAND() * <ScaleFactor> + <Offset>)` generates a random number with scale and offset.

So as `rand()` returns random number between `0` and `1`, if we scale by two, new range will be `0-2`, now if we shift it by -1, it should give you required result `-1 To +1`

```
Select RAND() * 2 + (-1) as MyRandomNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

This will choose if the number should be negative or positive and return a `RAND()` between `-1.0` and `1.0`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROUND(RAND()) = 0 THEN RAND()-1 ELSE RAND() END AS randNum
```